# how to save rating bar value using shared preferences?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, ratingbar

my "rate the app" is in navigation drawer.i have shared preferences for saving the value of rating bar but when I open again it is showing blank in rating bar.where am I getting wrong?
Following is my code:

```
 case R.id.nav_rate:

                    try {

                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                        View layout= null;
                        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                        layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rating, null);
                       final RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar)layout.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
                        builder.setTitle("Rate Us");
                        builder.setMessage("Thank you for rating us , it will help us to provide you the best service .");
                        builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                Float value = ratingBar.getRating();
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Rating is : "+value,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); // 0 - for private mode
                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
                                editor.putFloat("numStars", value);//put value
                                editor.commit();

                                float rating = pref.getFloat("numStars", 0f);
                                ratingBar.setRating(rating);//save
                            }
                        });
                        builder.setNegativeButton("No,Thanks", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                        builder.setCancelable(false);
                        builder.setView(layout);
                        builder.show();

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }}
```

Comment: try changing  prefs.getFloat("aFloat", 0f); to  prefs.getFloat("aFloat", 0.0f);

Comment: not working vinay jayaram

Comment: @Wini what are the type of results you can get in "value" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please write below code before `builder.setTitle` because You are only initializing after user presses OK button.

```
haredPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); // 0 - for private mode

                                float rating = pref.getFloat("numStars", 0f);
                                ratingBar.setRating(rating);
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you click and the dialog box opens up, it is opening as a new instance, So a solution would be to check before opening whether any data is present in your SharedPref variable, if there is any data present populate your UI based upon that data.